# Is there an area preserving map between spheres of different radii?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, area, volume, spheres

Does there exist a smooth map $f:(\mathbb{S}^2,r_1) \to (\mathbb{S}^2,r_2)$  which is area-preserving?

More precisely, I am considering two spheres with different radii, endowed with the round metrics. Let $\omega_1,\omega_2$ be the induced volume forms on the spheres. Is there an orienation-preserving immersion $\, f:(\mathbb{S}^2,r_1) \to (\mathbb{S}^2,r_2)$, such that $f^*\omega_2=\omega_1$?

Of course, such a map cannot be a diffeomorphism since for a volume-prserving diffeomorphism $f:M \to N$,

$$ \text{Vol}(N)=\int_N \text{Vol}_N=\int_M f^*\text{Vol}_N=\int_M \text{Vol}_M=\text{Vol}(M).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is an immersion, then it must be injective, since it is then a covering map and $S^2$ is simply connected. Therefore, it must be a diffeomorphism (by the same argument on the previous answer), and we have arrived at a contradiction based on what you already know.

---

Previous answer (under the assumption that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ were normalized volume forms).

There isn't. Your assumption implies $f$ has degree $1$. If $f$ is injective, it is a diffeomorphism and you are done (you are assuming that $f$ is an immersion: therefore, it is a submersion due to dimensional reasons and by the local form of submersions $f$ is open. It follows that $f$ is also surjective, proving that it is a diffeomorphism. You do not need to assume that $f$ is an immersion though, since you can use invariance of domain).

If $f$ is not injective, then there exists a point $y \in S^2$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ consists of more than one point. Since $f$ has degree $1$, it follows that $y$ is a critical point, a contradiction with the fact that $f$ is an immersion.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I follow your argument; 1) Why my assumption implies the degree is $1$? 2)  I do not see why $y$ should be a regular value. Any elaboration would be appreciated.

Comment: $\omega_2$ and $\omega_1$ generate the de Rham cohomology, so you are saying that $f^*: H^2(S^2) \simeq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \simeq H^2(S^2)$ is the identity (and therefore $f$ has degree $1$). The degree is also given by counting the pre-image of a regular value together with orientation. Since $f$ preserves orientation, this is mere counting. Therefore, if $y$ were a regular value, it would follow that $\mathrm{deg}(f) \geq 2$.

Comment: Thanks. But $\omega_1,2\omega_2$ also generate the cohomology, right? So, if you use them to identify the cohomology groups, wouldn't you get the map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ (or $2$)? How do you really "know" it is $1$? I guess I am missing something basic from differential\algebraic topology. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @AsafShachar By "generator" of the de Rham cohomology and sometimes "volume form", it is not unusual that we mean a form which integrates $1$, which led me to realize that I assumed this was the case when you said "induced volume form". Sorry for the confusion, I'll try to think on how to correct the argument. However, a direct argument using the induced map on cohomology and the equivalence of definitions of degree shows that we must have $r_1^2/r_2^2$ an integer.

Comment: @AsafShachar Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! your updated solution is very nice, really. BTW, I am not entirely sure what do you mean when you say that your constructed map is "area-preserving"- it is not an immersion (as you wrote) hence the pullback $f^*\omega$ of any $2$-form on the target sphere would be zero. So, this map cannot preserve the volume (area) forms (pointwise). Perhaps you meant area-preservation in some measure-theoretic sense?

Comment: @AsafShachar You are correct. The computation was in cohomology classes, I had overseen that $f^*\omega_2=\omega_1$ (the $2$-forms themselves).